# Iterating through files in a folder with sed

Tags: for-loop, sed

I've a list of csv-files and would like to use a for loop to edit the content for each file. I'd like to do that with sed. I have this sed commands which works fine when testing it on one file:

```
sed 's/[ "-]//g'
```

So now I want to execute this command for each file in a folder. I've tried this but so far no luck:

```
for i in *.csv; do sed 's/[ "-]//g' > $i.csv; done
```

I would like that he would overwrite each file with the edit performed by sed. The sed commands removes all spaces, the " and the '-' character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Small changes,

```
for i in *.csv
do 
    sed -i 's/[ "-]//g' "$i"
done
```

**Changes**

- when you iterate through the `for` you get the filenames in `$i` as example `one.csv`, `two.csv` etc. You can directly use these as input to the `sed` command.
- `-i` Is for inline changes, the sed will do the substitution and updates the file for you. No output redirection is required.
- In the code you wrote, I guess you missed any inputs to the `sed` command

Comment: for OSX, you may want to update the command to `sed -i'.original' 's/[ "-]//g' -e "$i"`

Answer (score 0):

In my case i want to replace every first occurrence of a particular string in each line for several text files, i've use the following:

```
//want to replace 16 with 1 in each files only for the first occurance
sed -i 's/16/1/' *.txt
```

In your case, In terminal you can try this

```
sed 's/[ "-]//g' *.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

In certain scenarios it might be worth considering `find`ing the files and executing a command on them like explained in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25923) (as stated there, make sure `echo $PATH` doesn't contain `.`)

```
find /path/to/csv/ -type f '*.csv' -execdir sed -i 's/[ "-]//g' {} \;
```

here we:

- `find` all files (type f) which end with `.csv` in the folder `/path/to/csv/`
- `sed` the found files in place, ie we replace the original files with the changed version instead of creating numbered csv files ($i.csv)